# Scraping images using Beautiful Soup and cant find the img/src tags

Tags: python, image, beautifulsoup

I am writing a beautiful Soup script that looks like this:

```
 for i in urls:
    url = remove_extra_char_in_values(i)
    response_get = requests.get(url)
    if response_get.status_code == 200:
        site = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS).text
        bs = BeautifulSoup(site, 'html.parser')
        images = bs.find_all('img', {'src': re.compile('.jpg')})
        for image in images:
            name = image['alt']
            images_link = image['src']

            with open(name.replace(' ', '-') + '.jpg', 'wb') as f:
                img = requests.get(images_link)
                f.write(img.content)
                print('Writing: ', name)
    elif response_get.status_code != 200:
        print('could not download link: ', url)
```

I am trying to pull images from tags that look link this:

```
<img data-test-id="Img" 
src="https://content.api.news/v3/images/bin/be02edb43dcdddb2e9d81eab1080cda1?width=1440" 
srcset="https://content.api.news/v3/images/bin/be02edb43dcdddb2e9d81eab1080cda1?width=1440 
100w, https://content.api.news/v3/images/bin/be02edb43dcdddb2e9d81eab1080cda1?width=1440 200w, 
https://content.api.news/v3/images/bin/be02edb43dcdddb2e9d81eab1080cda1?width=1440 320w, 
https://content.api.news/v3/images/bin/be02edb43dcdddb2e9d81eab1080cda1?width=1440 360w, 
https://content.api.news/v3/images/bin/be02edb43dcdddb2e9d81eab1080cda1?width=1440 375w, 
https://content.api.news/v3/images/bin/be02edb43dcdddb2e9d81eab1080cda1?width=1440 400w, 
https://content.api.news/v3/images/bin/be02edb43dcdddb2e9d81eab1080cda1?width=1440 414w, 
https://content.api.news/v3/images/bin/be02edb43dcdddb2e9d81eab1080cda1?width=1440 640w, 
https://content.api.news/v3/images/bin/be02edb43dcdddb2e9d81eab1080cda1?width=1440 720w, 
https://content.api.news/v3/images/bin/be02edb43dcdddb2e9d81eab1080cda1?width=1440 750w, 
https://content.api.news/v3/images/bin/be02edb43dcdddb2e9d81eab1080cda1?width=1440 768w, 
https://content.api.news/v3/images/bin/be02edb43dcdddb2e9d81eab1080cda1?width=1440 828w, 
https://content.api.news/v3/images/bin/be02edb43dcdddb2e9d81eab1080cda1?width=1440 1024w, 
https://content.api.news/v3/images/bin/be02edb43dcdddb2e9d81eab1080cda1?width=1440 1280w, 
https://content.api.news/v3/images/bin/be02edb43dcdddb2e9d81eab1080cda1?width=1440 1366w, 
https://content.api.news/v3/images/bin/be02edb43dcdddb2e9d81eab1080cda1?width=1440 1440w, 
https://content.api.news/v3/images/bin/be02edb43dcdddb2e9d81eab1080cda1?width=1440 1536w, 
https://content.api.news/v3/images/bin/be02edb43dcdddb2e9d81eab1080cda1?width=1440 1920w, 
https://content.api.news/v3/images/bin/be02edb43dcdddb2e9d81eab1080cda1?width=1440 2048w, 
https://content.api.news/v3/images/bin/be02edb43dcdddb2e9d81eab1080cda1?width=1440 2560w, 
https://content.api.news/v3/images/bin/be02edb43dcdddb2e9d81eab1080cda1?width=1440 2732w, 
https://content.api.news/v3/images/bin/be02edb43dcdddb2e9d81eab1080cda1?width=1440 2880w, 
https://content.api.news/v3/images/bin/be02edb43dcdddb2e9d81eab1080cda1?width=1440 3840w" 
sizes="(min-width: 1400px) 100vw, (min-width: 1200px) 100vw, (min-width: 980px) 100vw, (min- 
width: 600px) 100vw, 100vw" class="Img-ifujty gIUKwk"
```

The link has img/src, but not picking it up, does **'data-test-id="Img"'** have something to do with it, or class at the end? If so, how do I include these with img/scr in find_all('img', {'src': re.compile('.jpg')})? Does not appear to use JS either.

While im here, how to get BS to go through all the webpages, get images from the entire site? No just the page being called.

**An Edit to be clear.**

The script does not download images from the site in question. In this case its https://www.vogue.com.au/vogue-living

Rgs,

Comment: You got that image tag, right? I didn't understand what's your exact problem!

Comment: The script simply does not scrape any images from the site (https://www.vogue.com.au/vogue-living)... others it does

Comment: You want to scrape all of the images from this site? You should put that link in the question also try edit and do that!

Comment: some pages use JavaScript to add elements but `requests`/`Beautifulsoup` can't run JavaScript. Other pages uses JavaScript for `lazy loading` - `src` display empty image and when you scroll then JavaScript get real URL from other place - like `data-...` - and replace image in `src` - and then you have to use URL from `data-...` instead of `src`. So first turn off JavaScript in browser and open your page in browser to see what BeautifulSoup can get without JavaScript

Comment: server may also check other elements - like cookies, IP - and send fake image when something is wrong - ie, to block [hot linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_linking)

Comment: when I load page in browser without JavaScript then I get empty page - you may have to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: yeap furas you are correct. Selenium it is. tks